# Outer MouseArea loses 'containsMouse' when cursor enters inner MouseArea

Tags: qml, qt6

I have a QML Item which behaves as a button. For simplicity lets assume it is an `Item` with `MouseArea`. I use this `MouseArea` to detect clicks but also to know when button is hovered because I perform some additional visual changes when it happens.

Then I add this button as a child of another `Item` (lets call it ButtonParent) with `MouseArea` with 'hoverEnabled' set to `true`.

When mouse cursor enters ButtonParent, its `MouseArea` will set `containsMouse` to true, but as soon as I enter button area, `containsMouse` for ButtonParent will be set to `false` which is undesirable.

How can I make it work as I want? I'd like to avoid doing any changes in button item, which is meant to be universal/reusable item.

Here is sample code demonstrating this issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3


Rectangle {
    id: outerItem
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "blue"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onContainsMouseChanged: {
            if (containsMouse) {
                console.log("Mouse entered blue item")
            } else {
                console.log("Mouse left blue item")
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        width: 100
        height: 100

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            propagateComposedEvents: true

            onContainsMouseChanged: {
                if (containsMouse) {
                    console.log("Mouse entered red item")
                } else {
                    console.log("Mouse left red item")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by doint 2 changes:

1.) stack the child under the MouseArea of the parent.

2.) let the onPositionChanged event in the child bubble up to the parent

See the coments in the code snipped.

```
Rectangle {
    id: outerItem
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "blue"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onContainsMouseChanged: {
            if (containsMouse) {
                console.log("Mouse entered blue item")
            } else {
                console.log("Mouse left blue item")
            }
        }

        // stack child under mouse area
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            width: 100
            height: 100

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                propagateComposedEvents: true

                onPositionChanged: (mouse) => {
                    // propagate mouse event to parent
                    mouse.accepted = false;
                }

                onContainsMouseChanged: {
                    if (containsMouse) {
                        console.log("Mouse entered red item")
                    } else {
                        console.log("Mouse left red item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is enought to put inner `Rectangle` into outer `MouseArea` to make it work. No propagation needs to be enabled.

Comment: That is even better!